# How To Fix: "Expression is Ambiguous".

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an app that can help you calculate sales tax on an item. Of course the app requires multiplication But I keep encountering the error:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Can you help me? I'm new to swift so also try to explain why I am incorrect. This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Item: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Tax: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Answer: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        let a = Item.text
        let conversionRate = Tax
        let b = Int(a!)! * conversionRate
        Answer.text = ("\(b)")
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `conversionRate` is of type `UITextField` and your'e trying to multiply it by an `Int`, you need to cast `conversionRate` to `Int` and then use it in multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to multiply a variable of UITextField type with a variable of Int. Try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Item: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Tax: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Answer: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let a = Int(Item.text ?? "0") else { return }
        guard let conversionRate = Int(Tax.text ?? "0") else { return }
        let b = a * conversionRate
        Answer.text = ("\(b)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is your attempt to multiply an `Int` and a `UITextField`.

You attempt to create an `Int` from `Item.text` but you make no similar attempt to convert `Tax.text` to a number.

There are also many other issues with your code. You are using the `!` operator too much and your app will crash as a result.

And your naming conventions need to be improved. Variables and methods should start with lowercase letters.

Here's your code as it should be written:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tax: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        if let itemStr = item.text, let taxStr = tax.text, let itemVal = Int(itemStr), let taxVal = Int(taxStr) {
            let result = itemVal * texVal
            answer.text = "\(result)"
        } else {
            answer.text = "Invalid values"
        }
    }
}
```